# How do I troubleshoot the "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol 'end-of-file' when expecting one of the following" error in Griddb?

Tags: sql, eof, griddb, pls-00103

**My Code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_employee_name (p_id IN NUMBER, p_name OUT VARCHAR)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT name INTO p_name
  FROM employees
  WHERE id = p_id;
END;
/

BEGIN
  get_employee_name(1, v_name);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee name: ' || v_name);
END;
```

I'm trying to execute this query below but got this error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol 'end-of-file' when expecting one of
> the following

Comment: and where is v_name declared?